# What is the purpose of : public static DateTime ToDateTime(DateTime value) in the .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am maintaining an existing project, and I found this line of code:

```
Datetime someDate = ....;
var anotherDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(someDate);
```

At first, I expected that `someDate` is converted to a string by calling the `ToString` method on it implicitly, but I was wrong. As I pressed F12 on the method I see the definition of that method in the `System.Convert` class, which is like the following:

```
// Summary: Returns the specified System.DateTime object; no actual conversion is performed.
// Parameters:
//   value: A date and time value.
// Returns:
//     value is returned unchanged.
public static DateTime ToDateTime(DateTime value);
```

**First** Why does the .NET framework have a method like this in the first place, as the documentation says that this method does Nothing? 
**Second** While I am refactoring the code, can I safely remove the call for this method without affecting the behavior?

Comment: Common in early .NET versions to implement late binding, before Linq, EF and *dynamic* made the job easier.  Mapping data from a dbase table row for example, the dbase provider might supply a DateTime based on the column type.  Omitting that Convert method would make such code too painful.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is because the `Convert` class is intented to work with types that implement the [`IConvertible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) interface.

This interface contains methods to convert an implementing type to CLR types like `decimal`, `byte`, `DateTime` etc. Each of those types implement `IConvertible` themselves.

So, `Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime d)` isn't the only method that does "nothing". It exists for any of those CLR types implementing `IConvertible` as well, e.g. `Convert.ToChar(char c)`. It just comes from the fact that all of these types implement `IConvertible`.

You can read more about this in the [comments](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs) of the source code of the `Convert` class.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can remove it. It is completely redundant. As for why: I *guess* someone thought it was a good idea to avoid people accidentally calling `Convert.ToDateTime(object)` (which would be implicit) - which would involve a box, type-check and unbox. Frankly that seems like a silly reason to me, along the lines of "write bad code, get bad results".

Answer (score 6):

As you can see in the [current BCL sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,6ece67905d76d903):

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(DateTime value) {
        return value;
}
```

there is no actual conversion, so you can safely remove those calls.

Answer (score 3):

Though I agree with answers here so far, I guess there is also another aspect to it, which is code generation. In the early days of .NET, code generation was very often done using CodeDOM (and sometimes still is, e.g. with the WinForms Designer). CodeDOM does not really track the type of variables as this type might not be known at the time of code generation (for example if the type is also generated). Therefore, it is a lot easier to just generate a reference to a method `ToDate` and have the compiler figure out which of the overloads to use. Given that these methods are non-virtual, they can be inlined and there is not even a performance penalty.

That said, I am pretty sure the WinForms Designer code generator does not use this method, at least not in .NET 2.0, the earliest version that I have worked with.